# Unable to capture text inside new window in Java Selenium Headless browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm running all my test suites on Jenkins which is deployed on AWS EC2 instance. There is a scenario where when I click on a button, new small window opens up and I'm doing assertion for the text visible inside the small newly opened window. But my tests are failing when I run using **Headless** mode. But, same scripts works fine when I run scripts locally without opting for headless browser.

The issue here is the scripts are failing because of headless browser since it's unable to capture text inside small window which has opened after click of button.
This class is extending InitiateDriver class which explained. Below class is trying to fetch text which is visible inside the new window which just opened after clicked on SignInWithGSuiteSSOClick() button.

```
Here is the code:
// click on a button
GSuiteobject.SignInWithGSuiteSSOClick().click(); 
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
// Here trying to capture text inside new window opened up basically gmail window to enter email 
String signInHeader = GSuiteobject.GsuiteSignInHeader().getText();
Assert.assertEquals(signInHeader, "Sign in");
GSuiteobject.GsuiteEmail().sendKeys("example@gmail.com");
```

InitiateDriver.java

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("--headless");
 options.addArguments("--window-size=1920, 1080");
 options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The same code works in browser mode but not in headless. But the driver will be initialized but it fails only while capturing text. Please help me out I'm stuck here and unable to execute it on Jenkins as a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

Headless chrome browser's gmail UI will be different from actual gmail UI(latest). Hence it fails when we run headless chrome for automating gmail login since xpaths will differ. We can validate that by taking Screenshot by running on headless and normal browser.

I suggest to take screenshot using both headless and normal browser. To check on xpaths for headless we can try driver.getPageSource() method.